# Windows Service Monitor a Remote Folder

Tags: .net

As the title implys, when I use the .Net System.IO.FileSystemWatcher to monitor a local folder, it works prefect. But it failed when I tried to monitor a remote folder on a different domain using the ServiceAccount.User and provided Username and Password for the connection. In truth, this Username and Password can login on the specified machine, which the remote folder I want to monitor located in. When I tried to Install the Service, it replied "Access is denied".

Comment: If you want to start the service on remote machine, I suppose this user needs admin rights.

Comment: Thank you Goran for your quick resposne.This is the admin account for the remote machine, I susposed the machine I install the windows service is in a different domain with the remote machine. When the windows service attempt to detect the remote folder using FileSysteWathcer class, the remote machine would deny this request due the untrusted domain. So I did not know what to do with this FileSystemWatcher class. It works well in the Winform with the same code, but failed in the Windows Service. It makes me  really confused.